# Why is esc and bs used in Packer boot_command?

Tags: virtualbox, boot, packer

I am trying to learn Packer making it possible for me to create templates/golden images for my VMs. In the long run, I want to be able to have Packer in CI/CD pipeline constantly updating images for my VMs.

Now I am trying to create an image for an Ubuntu desktop ISO using `virtualbox-iso` as my builder type. This means I have met new challenges in order to automate this process, like the `"boot_command"`, `preseed.cfg` and `vmlinuz` to mention a few.

The first thing I want to understand is `boot_command` using an example found online. The definition:

> boot_command specifies the keys to type when the virtual machine is first booted in order to start the OS installer.

Example:

```
 "boot_command": [
  "<esc><wait>",
  "<esc><wait>",
  "<enter><wait>",
  "/install/vmlinuz<wait>",
  " auto<wait>",
       ...
```

I have seen many examples using commands like: `bs` and `esc`. This does not makes sense to me since I have never used those during a computer or VM boot.

My question(s) are:
1. Why are these commands used?
2. What do they do in this particular case?

Thanks.